# how to know at what date time my ebs volume got unattached

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have to delete my unattached ebs volumes only if that ebs is unattached for last weeks.
for that I need to find exact date & time of ebs got unattached from ec2.

Comment: Check CloudTrial for that info.

Comment: i need to do this all using python boto3

Comment: Yes, you can query CloudTrial using python if you have CloudTrial Trials enabled.

Comment: Or, query AWS Config (if you have a Recorder activated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this-
Manual- Use AWS cloudtrail to find the event and get the timestamp from event. Delete the resource manually.

Automatically- Create a script, probably using python boto3 to find unattached ebs for 1 week and delete. Either schedule it using Lambda or add it as a cron in any server having access to required aws resources.